# left join using stringdist_join() is returning more rows than started with.

Tags: r, string, boolean-logic

I am just working on a left join with stringdist_join() and am having trouble, in that my output has more rows than my original "left' data frame.

```
  nrow(records_nona)
   #output : 603

  nrow(institutions)
  # output : 981

  records_nona <- stringdist_left_join(records_nona, institutions, 
   by = c("tm_1_undergradu" = "Institution.Name"))

  nrow(records_nona)
  # output: 635
```

I am not sure, what I could be messing up here for this to be possible. Or my understanding of left joins is wrong. Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Probably you have got multiple matches for the same row...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution, The left join was producing duplicates due to the approximation of the join, So I just needed to reduce the max_dist = 1. (the default is max_dist = 2). And I now have the correct number of rows.